# Laravel - Saving Model not working if triggered from C#

Tags: c#, php, laravel

I am using C# to make a request to my webserver like this so I can save the data from the client into my model.

This is the route:

```
Route::get('client/register', 'ClientController@store');
```

C# request:

```
string response = Network.sendWebRequest("http://localhost/myproject/public/client/register?identity=" + getIdentity());
```

As you can see I send a GET request with `identity` and a `base64` encoded string as value.
Then in my store function I decode the base64 encoded string, explode it and try to save it in my database (**HINT**: The database table is empty, so don't worry the record does not exist already)

**ClientController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo "store function";        


    $clientIdentityB64 = request('identity');

    if (empty($clientIdentityB64)) {  return "empty";  }

    $clientIdentity = base64_decode($clientIdentityB64);
    $identityArr = explode(";", $clientIdentity);

    $clientQuery = Client::select("id")
            ->where("base64Id", "=", $clientIdentityB64)
            ->get()
            ->first();

    if (is_null($clientQuery)) {

        $client = new Client();
        $client->ip = $request->ip();
        $client->base64Id = $clientIdentityB64;
        $client->userName = $identityArr[0];
        $client->userDomainName = $identityArr[1];
        $client->machineName = $identityArr[2];
        $client->osVersion = $identityArr[3];
        $client->userAgent = $request->userAgent();

        $client->save();
    }        
}
```

However, It does not save the model into the database if I make the request. You can see that I output `store function` at the top of the store function, but I only get the response if I remove `$client->save()` from the code.
If `$client->save()` is in the code then I get this response:

```
Exception: System.Net.WebException: Request canceled: disconnected
   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   bei Helper.Network.sendWebRequest(String URL) in C:\Users....
```

I already echoed out all the values with success, only the save function does not work even though the values are there.

However, It does work If I call the following URL from a normal webbrowser: `http://localhost/myproject/public/client/register?identity=somebase64encodedhash`.

How to solve this?

---

This is my network class which I used above:

```
public static class Network
{
    public static string sendWebRequest(string URL)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);

        try {
            System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            return (string)streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            return "Exception: " + e;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

**Request from Webbrowser:**

```
GET /myproject/public/client/register?identity=LO0dzILO0E5ULO0IBXaW5kb3dzIEDUNLO0JMQUNLO01pY3Jvc29mdCBXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMi45MjAwLjA= HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3 Client-Ip: 147.153.195.175 Connection: keep-alive Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkhPNW9yeVhkNGFiQWFnWUtFQ2FRREE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZm1yR1NxN0tvTEFJSTNoYnJWdmNRWWZEVTRDOWVYUHJNemhDWCs4TFY4VnNoU2J5ZXNha3dPNHAwNHlKc0lHMlRGQUdiUE9BdnJcL2NDb1l4RytYSFJRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI2ODliODM1ZDU4NzFlMTcxNmUyNGMzYjNhYTBkNGU0NjI3NDQ4MmYxZTFiZTg5YWNjMmEyZWFiMDliYWExZjY4In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ijl0Mnlid0xkdTRRQVh2UDZhXC95MzFBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InR4eCtTRVg5XC81YTU3dHB1azluVHpYemw5a2ZkbnBEMGdsRllGSXFIajFJSUdWcitwSTFQS1pWXC9LUlR3Vzh0eExSY3Via2xwOTBhVG5kZXVzRXdWbGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijg5MmZiNDMxOTFhMGQzNjMxNmM0NzI1NzAyOTk3ZTU4ODkwMzdkYzM3YTIxZTU3M2MzMWYzYjM5NTI1OWVhZDQifQ%3D%3D Dnt: 1 Host: localhost Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0 Via: 223.100.9.3 X-Forwarded-For: 36.2.247.179
```

**Request from C# Application:**

```
GET /myproject/public/client/register?identity=LO0dzILO0E5ULO0IBXaW5kb3dzIEDUNLO0JMQUNLO01pY3Jvc29mdCBXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMi45MjAwLjA= HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

**Hint**: I changed the base64 string to something else...

### UPDATE

I changed my Network class to this, so I can attach an empty cookieContainer to the request. But it does not change the request at all.

```
public static class Network
{
    public static string sendWebRequest(string URL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        try {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            return (string)streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            return "Exception: " + e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a required cookie?

Comment: I don't think that a cookie is required. I tested it in private browser mode

Comment: I would compare requests in something like fiddler. It is probably cookie, some header or caller IP.

Comment: You are right, I added the requests to my posts. There is no session and xsrf token in the request from c#. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: User [WebHeaderCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/965xw3x5(v=vs.110).aspx) in your web request.

Comment: But from where do I get the necessary XSRF Token and the session string?

Comment: If your request be cookie enabled you will get it automatically.

Comment: So I first have to get the cookie then sending another request with the token and session key as headers? But the XSRF Token does change with every request?! I think I have to solve this without laravel.

Comment: Send request with an attached empty cookieContainer and it will automatically get the cookie and send subsequent request with the same webRequest.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. I updated my post

Comment: Mimic what you do with the browser. You should visit a URL which is responsible for assigning `XSRF-TOKEN`. Just do that call with a cookie enabled `WebRequest`.

Comment: @Xaqron, Ok I see, I will try it. Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a webBrowser element to my C# Form and calling the URL from the browser like this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/myproject/public/client/register?identity=" + getIdentity());
```